# errors when embedding file with swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

i try to embbed a file for my automatic response.
So i have this in my controller :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $imgUrl = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('http://hpics.li/5395483'));
    $message->setSubject('Demande de devis bien reçue !')
                ->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($devis->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'OAHDevisBundle:Devis:devis_email.html.twig',array('url'=>$imgUrl)
                        ),
                    'text/html'
                    );

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

but i have the following error :

```
Attempted to load class "Swift_Image" from namespace "OAH\DevisBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Is there a problem in my code ? What use can i add to fix my problem? Thank you

Comment: You forgot to add the slash to denote the global namespace for `\Swift_Image`

Comment: Thant you ! i'm sorry...

Comment: No worries. It happens